# I upgraded Kubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 and can not start my PC

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I am new to Kubuntu or Ubuntu. I upgraded Kubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 and cannot start my PC. During boot process I get this error message:

```
Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive (emergency.target has 'start' job queued, but 'stop' is included in transaction).
```

Comment: Having exactly the same issue with ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 upgrade. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded ubuntu 20.04 with kde to 21.04, enabled display scaling, then it couldn't boot with the identical error message, but it sometimes boots into GUI successfully.
Then I turned display scaling off when it boots up into KDE, then the problem is solved temporarily.
I'm not sure whether it works for others, but you can try it. If your PC can't boot into GUI directly, try to boot into the tty console instead of GUI, then start the display manager manually, finally turn off display scaling.

Comment: I would suggest to perform a fresh install of Kubuntu 21.10.